# What happens if I check "Require Content Approval" as "Yes" and then I create a "Publishing Approval" workflow on it?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I checked the option "Require Content approval " in list setting and then I created a "Publishing Approval " workflow for adding a item in list . But I was not able to see the added item in approver's list until the creator approves the item.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new item or when you modify an existing item in a list or a document library after you enable content approval for that list or document library, the item is **marked as Pending**. **Pending items** are only **visible to the user who created or modified the item** and to users with the **Manage Lists right**. Pending items are not visible to users until the item is approved.

Read more over here: 
[Overview of the Content Approval Feature and the Approval Status of Items in a List or in a Document Library Print Print Email Email](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825239)